# Integrating fullPage.js and google map api

Tags: google-maps, integration, fullpage.js

I'm trying to integrate the fullPage.js and google map api, but it seems that it isn't not working.

Below is the sample jsFiddle of google map api and fullpage.js that I'm trying to integrate.

[jsFiddle of Google Map](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ytu9/8/)

[jsFiddle of fullPage.js](http://jsfiddle.net/skLn4hkh/)

The result that I want to create is similar to this, as you notice the google map (acting as a background) is embedded to fullpage.js (The sample image is just an edited picture only)

[image]

**id="canvass" is my google map**

```
<div id="canvass"></div>
```

Then this is my first section including the several slides.

```
 <div class="section"  id="section1">
<div class="slide">
    <div id="canvass"></div>
    <img src="images/index_images/BG_Slide.png" width="750" height="200"/>
    <p>
        <strong>MULTI-MACH INTERNATIONAL (PHILS)</strong> has been one of the Philippines leading players in the supply and distribution of leading<br>brands of various foodservice equipment from various parts of the world (esp. Europe, USA, and Japan) that are known and endorsed<br>by respected international consultants and renown practitioners in food service and construction fields.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="slide">
    <p><strong>MULTI-MACH INTERNATIONAL (PHILS)</strong> has been one of the Philippines leading players in the supply and distribution of leading<br>brands of various foodservice equipment from various parts of the world (esp. Europe, USA, and Japan) that are known and endorsed<br>by respected international consultants and renown practitioners in food service and construction fields.</p>
</div>
<div class="slide">
    <p><strong>MULTI-MACH INTERNATIONAL (PHILS)</strong> has been one of the Philippines leading players in the supply and distribution of leading<br>brands of various foodservice equipment from various parts of the world (esp. Europe, USA, and Japan) that are known and endorsed<br>by respected international consultants and renown practitioners in food service and construction fields.</p>
</div>
<div class="slide">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, nam dolorem enim quod placeat tempore praesentium nobis quam maxime eum?<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum facere excepturi minus corrupti nesciunt dolorum!<br>by respected international consultants and renown practitioners in food service and construction fields.</p>
</div>
```

The following are my attempt to get that kind of result.

1. Put it inside the 1st section, on the 1st slide. I'm thinking that it will act as a background
2. Create another section dedicated for showing the google map only (i'm just testing it, but it seems that it also didn't work)

Do you have any idea on what I am doing wrong or is it really not compatible to fullpage.js? Please note that I'm using codeigniter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the initialization of the map inside the `afteRender` callback provided by fullpage.js as detailed [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterrender):

> **afterRender()** 
>   This callback is fired just after the structure of the page is generated. **This is the callback you want to use to initialize other plugins or fire any code which requires the document to be ready** (as this plugin modifies the DOM to create the resulting structure).

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/290/)

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    afterRender: function () {
        //Start the whole shabang when DOM and APIs are ready by calling initialize()
        initialize();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are really great @alvaro. Thank you very much for your countless support to the users of fullPage.js. Thanks!